# How to select all images using jquery and give them an width?

Tags: jquery

I want to select all images with jQuery and give them an style ?

> These photos are very big

```
<div class="body">
   <img src="some-src" > 
   <img src="some-src" >
   <img src="some-src" >
   <img src="some-src" >
</div>
```

I want to do something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.body').('img').foreach().css({"width":"200px"});
});
```

How can i do it ?

Comment: `$('img').css('width','200px')` or, in your CSS: `img { width: 200px; }` Where did you get stuck when you tried to write this?

Comment: Any basic tutorial on using jQuery would answer this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.body img').css("width","200px");
});
```

or this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.body').each(function () {
        $('img').css("width","200px");
    })
});
```

or you can use css like this :

```
.body img{
  width : 200px;
}
```

or

```
img{
  width : 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to use for each you can select all images like below method.

```
<div class="body">
   <img src="some-src" > 
   <img src="some-src" >
   <img src="some-src" >
   <img src="some-src" >
</div>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.body img').css("width","200px");
});
```